# Redirect Output to a file which is variably defined

Tags: windows, csv, awk

I have an awk script which is parsing a CSV part of the fields need to be written to another file based on the contents of another field in the file. Example Given a CSV:

```
  Col1,Col2,Col3
```

The awk script would output a file named Col1.txt with the contents of Col2 and Col3. In searching it seems that using a print redirect should work. I've tried:

```
  printf("%s\t%s", Col2, Col3) > Col1
```

But I get an the error message "Can't redirect to 'Col1' (Invalid argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to use double quotes like `> "Col1.txt"`

If `Col1` is an `awk` variable containing the basename of a filename, you could do

```
printf ("%s\t%s", Col2, Col3) > (Col1 ".txt")
```

Or maybe you want to parse the CSV file like:

```
awk -F, '{printf("%s\t%s", $2, $3) > "Col1.txt"}' file.csv
```

and you may also want to add a newline after each row. As `printf("%s\t%s\n", $2, $3)`

Comment: This worked, but unlike calls to system which need to be escaped with ", this breaks if you have the " in them. I don't know why, but once I did that this solution worked perfectly.